# Sql requests,Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I tried to do it,but something is  wrong,can help me,i realy need it

```
recordid | patientid | doctorid | dateofrecord
----------+-----------+----------+--------------
1 | 1 | 2 | 2020-02-01
2 | 2 | 1 | 2020-05-12
3 | 3 | 2 | 2020-12-23
4 | 1 | 3 | 2020-04-01
5 | 3 | 1 | 2020-11-02
6 | 1 | 3 | 2020-02-01
7 | 3 | 4 | 2020-02-01
8 | 4 | 4 | 2020-05-12
9 | 5 | 2 | 2020-12-23
10 | 1 | 1 | 2020-04-01
```

table with doctors

```
id | firstname | lastname | speciality | dateofbirth | nurseid
----+-----------+--------------+------------+-------------+---------
1 | Vitalii | Surkov | Ortoped | 2001-01-13 | 1
2 | Andriy | Kolomiets | Psyholog | 2000-04-19 | 2
3 | Doctor | Komarovskiy | Pediatr | 1945-04-09 | 3
4 | Taras | Shevchenko | Okulist | 1932-12-03 | 4
5 | Oleksandr | Nechiporenko | Hirurg | 1984-10-10 | 5
```

table with patients

```
id | firstname | lastname | dateofbirth | districtid | sex
----+-----------+-------------+-------------+------------+--------
1 | Andriy | Shevchenko | 2000-11-23 | 1 | male
2 | Lebron | James | 1998-12-01 | 2 | male
3 | Lesya | Ukrainka | 1956-03-02 | 3 | female
4 | Vitalii | Shevchenko | 2001-01-13 | 2 | male
5 | Andriy | James | 2000-04-19 | 1 | male
8 | Petro | Poroshenko | 1934-12-12 | 2 | male
6 | Angela | Merkel | 1965-05-05 | 1 | female
7 | Igor | Kolomoiskiy | 1989-10-02 | 3 | male
```

So I need to determine who else visited the doctors on the day when he made an appointment with patient "A" and  and also i need to show which doctor is at this record.
I use PostgreSql 12.

Comment: "something is wrong" is not a question.  please read [ask] and post a [mcve].  thanks

Comment: I don't see a Patient A in your sample data. What is the expected output, can you share that result set?

Comment: @JNevill so for example we have patient A(1 | Andriy | Shevchenko | 2000-11-23 | 1 | male) in table patients and he has a record in records table (1 | 1 | 2 | 2020-02-01) so i need to outup all records with a similar dateofrecord with patient A for example  expected output  is a patients with theirs id , and doctor

Comment: @JNevill I will be grateful if you help me

Comment: Just the same doctor as patient A or any other doctor as well?

Comment: @JNevill any other doctor will be as well

Answer (score 1):

The following should work if I understood it correctly. It will give you all other patients that had any doctor appointments on the same day as patient a:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM records r
JOIN patients p
   ON r.patientid = p.id
JOIN doctors d
   ON r.doctorid  = d.id
WHERE r.dateofrecord in 
   (SELECT r2.dateofrecord 
    FROM records r2 
    WHERE r2.patientid = 1)
AND r.patientid <> 1;
```